# How to add a new language string in WordPress?

Tags: php, string, wordpress, translation, language-translation

Basically I want to change the words "Previous post" and "Next Post" for "Previous Work" and "Next work" in this site: http://fontaneriaborja.com/en/portfolio-view/solar-panels-swimming-pool/

I have gone into /wp-content/themes/CherryFramework/loop/loop-single-portfolio.php and found this code:

```
<!--BEGIN .pager .single-pager -->
        <ul class="pager single-pager">
        <?php if (get_previous_post()) : ?>
            <li class="previous"><?php previous_post_link('%link', theme_locals("prev_post")) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if (get_next_post()) : ?>
            <li class="next"><?php next_post_link('%link', theme_locals("next_post")) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
<!--END .pager .single-pager -->
```

I believe that theme_locals("prev_post") and theme_locals("next_post") are the strings that call the text.

Ideally what I would like to do is to change and add a new string for something like theme_locals("prev_work") and theme_locals("next_work") that would generate two new translations to my .po files. However, is here where I get stuck.

It is a multi language WordPress 4.1.1 site using Polylang and a theme from Template Monster with the cherry plugin.

I have already searched around with no luck to understand how this works. So any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you for your time and thanks in advance to all of you.

Best

P.S.: I am a beginner in terms of web development.
P.S.2: I have posted this also on https://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-language-string-in-wordpress and I will try to keep both places updated if I find the solution.

POST EDIT:

As suggested by [danbahrami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4572608/danbahrami) I have found a php file with the function 'theme_local_init()' in /wp-content/themes/CherryFramework/includes/locals.php. Here is part of the code, I haven't put it all because is quite long:

```
<?php
function theme_local_init() {
    global $is_cherry_local_init, $cherry_locals_arr;
    if ($is_cherry_local_init) return true;

    $domain = CURRENT_THEME;
    $cherry_locals_arr = array(
        //general
        'no' => __('No', 'cherry'),
        'yes' => __('Yes', $domain),
        'slow_speed' => __('Slow', $domain),
        'normal_speed' => __('Normal', $domain),
        'fast_speed' => __('Fast', $domain),
        'normal_size' => __('Normal size', $domain),
        'large_size' => __('Large size', $domain),
        'font_size' => __('Font Size', $domain),
        'lineheight' => __('Lineheight', $domain),
        'font_face' => __('Font Face', $domain),
        'character_sets' => __('Character Sets', $domain),
        'font_style' => __('Font Style', $domain),
        'color' => __('Color', $domain),
        'import' => __('Import', $domain),
        'export' => __('Export', $domain),
        'done' => __('Done', $domain),
        'error' => __('Error', $domain),
        'success' => __('success', $domain),
        'upload' => __('Upload', $domain),
        'try_again' => __('try again', $domain),
        'finish' => __('Finish', $domain),
        'skip' => __('Skip this step', $domain),
        'install_next' => __('next', $domain),
        'none' => __('None', $domain),
        'date' => __('Date', $domain),
        'title' => __('Title', $domain),
        'info' => __('Info', $domain),
        'rand' => __('Random', $domain),
        'comment_count' => __('Comment count', $domain),
        'enable_lightbox' => __('Enable Lightbox', $domain),
        'enable_lightbox_desc' => __('Check this to enable the lightbox.', $domain),
        'permalink_to' => __('Permalink', $domain),
        'read_more' => __('Read more', $domain),
        'view_all' => __('View all', $domain),
        'width' => __('Width', $domain),
        'height' => __('Height', $domain),
        'excerpt_length' => __('Excerpt length (words):', $domain),
        'link_text' => __('Link Text:', $domain),
        'link_url' => __('Link URL', $domain),
        'standard' => __('Standard', $domain),
        'aside' => __('Aside', $domain),
        'quote' => __('Quote', $domain),
        'link' => __('Link', $domain),
        'image' => __('Image', $domain),
        'gallery' => __('Gallery', $domain),
        'audio' => __('Audio', $domain),
        'video' => __('Video', $domain),
        'categories' => __('Categories', $domain),
        'tags' => __('Tags', $domain),
        'show_all' => __('Show All', $domain),
        'search' => __('search', $domain),
        'go' => __('Go', $domain),
        'prev_post' => __('&laquo; Previous post', $domain),
        'next_post' => __('Next Post &raquo;', $domain),
```

I believe this last two lines are the ones in question but there is still more code.

Comment: The text is being returned by the 'theme_locals()' function. If you explore your theme files you will find that function defined somewhere... probably in the file called functions.php. If you cant and have a good code editor there should be a tool to search all files. try searching for 'function theme_locals' and paste everything in between the following {} brackets into your question that would be very helpful.

Comment: I think I have added what you need it. Hope this helps and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is change the last 2 lines of the `theme_local_init` function from...

```
'prev_post' => __('&laquo; Previous post', $domain),
'next_post' => __('Next Post &raquo;', $domain),
```

to...

```
'prev_post' => __('&laquo; Previous work', $domain),
'next_post' => __('Next work &raquo;', $domain),
```

If you're interested in learning more about how wordpress deals with translation you should read [The i18n page in the Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers). It may help you to understand how your theme works.

**UPDATE:** or if you want to only change the text in certain situations you could add more lines to your function e.g.

```
'prev_work' => __('&laquo; Previous work', $domain),
'next_work' => __('Next work &raquo;', $domain),
```

Then change the `post_link` functions in your template to use `prev_work` and `next_work` instead.

Then the next time you generate your PO file the new translatable strings will be added.

Hope that helps

Dan

Comment: Hi Dan, that would imply that it will change that phrase everywhere on the template. And I want to change those words only in that particular case. Would it work if I add two lines like 'prev_work' => __('&laquo; Previous work', $domain), 'next_work' => __('Next work &raquo;', $domain), ? But then, will it generate that lines into the .po files? Here is where I don't know how to proceed

Comment: I have updated my answer to address this... essentially yes you are correct, and when you generate your PO file the new strings will be included.

Comment: Thanks Dan, that worked to get to show now Next Work and Previous Work. However, I downloaded the PO file and I can't find the new string. Do I need to do anything to add it? I visited the Wordpress codex link before even posting this, but it was to difficult for me to understand.

Comment: Translation isn't that simple, wordpress wont automatically generate a .po file for you. you will need to download a software package called poedit and regenerate the .po file yourself.

Comment: I knew about the Poedit and I used it to open the file. However the .po file did not include the string for '&laquo; Previous work' or  'Next work &raquo;'. I opened with Sublime text and I can't see the strings there either Do I need to manually include any code into the .po file? BTW thanks for all your help

Comment: Ok, so I had to download the whole folder from my FTP and regenerate the .po file with Poedit and that worked. I am not quite sure if there is a workaround to this because is very tedious. Anyway this works and I want to say BIG THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP